# C#/.NET: How do I create a DNS record in an Azure DNS zone using the new ARM SDK?

Tags: .net, azure, dns, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk

I need to programmatically create a TXT DNS record in an Azure DNS zone. Using the `Azure.Management.Dns` package, this could be achieved like this:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Management.Dns;

var dnsClient = new DnsManagementClient(new DefaultAzureCredential()){SubscriptionId="mySubscriptionId"};
...
await dnsClient.RecordSets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, zoneName, recordSetName, RecordType.TXT, recordSet);
```

Now MS has marked the `Azure.Management.Dns` package as deprecated and recommends to use the `Azure.ResourceManager.Dns` package instead. [Microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-sdk) however still uses the deprecated package, including examples.

Unfortunately, I don't really see where [the documentation of the corresponding new ARM models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.dns.dnszoneresource?view=azure-dotnet) explains how to create a new TXT record, and sadly MS does not provide any examples with that one.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Edit: Originally claimed the ARM package would be in beta, turns out it is not.

Comment: **It isn't in beta**... it's at version 1.0.1 now: so where are you getting that from? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Dns/

Comment: `TXT` records are managed using `DnsTxtRecordData`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.dns.dnstxtrecorddata?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @Dai: My fault, for whatever reason I saw only beta versions in VS's NuGet Package Manager. Must have overlooked 1.0.1, sorry for that and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Dai: I understand I can create an `DnsTxtRecordData` object, but the question is how to add that record to the DNS zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new (post-2019) `Azure.ResourceManager.*` NuGet package libraries have adopted newer C# features like `IAsyncEnumerable`, which makes some operations nonobvious for discovery by those (like us) who expect a more conventional API design (so it actually took me a while to figure out how to answer your question).

But you'll want something like this:

### Step 1: Get an authenticated `ArmClient` instance and your target `SubscriptionResource`:

This works for me in Linqpad and console programs, though obviously you'll want to use `DefaultAzureCredential` in deployed code:

```
//#define ARGH_ITS_NOT_WORKING // Uncomment this if you're having AAD/Entra authX problems.

const String TENANT_ID       = "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee";
const String SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "ffffffff-1111-2222-3333-444444444444";

#if ARGH_ITS_NOT_WORKING
using AzureEventSourceListener listener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger();
#endif

InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions credsOpts = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions()
{
    DisableAutomaticAuthentication = true,
    TenantId = TENANT_ID
};

#if ARGH_ITS_NOT_WORKING
credsOpts.Diagnostics.IsAccountIdentifierLoggingEnabled = true;
#endif

InteractiveBrowserCredential creds = new InteractiveBrowserCredential( credsOpts );
AuthenticationRecord authRecord = await creds.AuthenticateAsync();

ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient( creds );

//

SubscriptionResource sub = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
if( sub.Id.SubscriptionId != SUBSCRIPTION_ID ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Unexpected default Subscription." );
```

### Step 2: Get the Zone, add records, submit:

- We have `ArmClient armClient` and `SubscriptionResource sub` from step 1.
- You'll need to add [`System.Linq.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) for `ToListAsync()`.
- The .`Dump()` method is an extension-method from [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/). You can safely remove those calls.
- The `GetDnsZonesAsync()` method is an extension-method on `Azure.ResourceManager.Dns.SubscriptionResourceExtensionClient`.

```
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Dns;

//

List<DnsZoneResource> dnsZones = await sub.GetDnsZonesAsync().ToListAsync();
DnsZoneResource zone0 = dnsZones.First().Dump();

DnsTxtRecordCollection txtRecords = zone0.GetDnsTxtRecords();

DnsTxtRecordData newTxtRecordValues = new DnsTxtRecordData()
{
    TtlInSeconds = 300, You must set a non-null TTL or the request will be rejected.
    DnsTxtRecords = 
    {
        new DnsTxtRecordInfo()
        {
            Values = 
            {
                "foo",
                "bar"
            }
        }
    }
};

ArmOperation<DnsTxtRecordResource> newResourceOp = await txtRecords.CreateOrUpdateAsync( WaitUntil.Completed, txtRecordName: "baz", data: newTxtRecordValues );
DnsTxtRecordResource newResource = newResourceOp.Value;

newResource.Dump();
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick! Not really difficult once you know how it's done, but I could not find any documentation outlining the whole process. Thanks again!